# The viewer node BACKGROUND image in my COMPOSITOR tab doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

The background (VIEWER NODE) image in my compositor tab seems to be affected by some bug. It wouldn't display the background image. But if you'd hold down the alt + v keys (to enlarge) at some point a part of the image (solid colour) suddenly pops up filling the tab's whole background. From there if you'd simply press the v key (to diminish) once, it'd disappear. But from there if you'd continue to enlarge, the solid color might change to that of a different pixel in the image yet would still be filling the entire background with that pixel. Trying to move the background image holding down the Alt + right mouse button is of no help - you could indefinitely do so without any result. I have attached a simplified file causing the problem herewith.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: No idea what's caused it, but press the 'N' key then the View tab and click 'Reset Backdrop'. The cursor returns to normal when you do that too!

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you that worked!!

Comment: Good! I'd still like to know what caused it though! :^)